# How do I remount a filesystem as read/write?

Tags: mount, filesystem

I'm trying to mount an hfsplus filesystem in a Xubuntu 12.04 VM (kernel version 3.2.0-23-generic) but when I type `mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdb3` in command line it returns `not mounted or bad option`. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 331, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /partition/identifier /mount/point
```

Where `mount/point` is `/partition/identifier`'s corresponding mountpoint, as listed by the following command:

```
mount -v | grep "^/" | awk '{print "\nPartition identifier: " $1  "\n Mountpoint: "  $3}'
```

---

For example, say that the above command gives this:

```
Partition identifier: /dev/sda1
 Mountpoint: /    

Partition identifier: /dev/sda2
 Mountpoint: /boot

Partition identifier: /dev/sda3
 Mountpoint: /test
```

The following would be the correct syntax. (We start by unmounting it, if it's already mounted.)

```
sudo umount /test
sudo umount /dev/sdb3
sudo mount -t hfsplus -o rw,remount -force /dev/sdb3 /media/untitled
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I have been using sudo, forgot to include that. I'm by no means an advanced linux user, so I'm not exactly sure what I'm supposed to be seeing in /etc/fstab. However, when i type "df -h" it tells me that the hfsplus filesystem is mounted at /dev/sdb3

Comment: I see what you're saying now, "mount -v | grep ^/" returns "/devsdb3 on /media/untitled".

I tried "sudo mount -o remount,rw /media/untitled" and got the same problem-not mounted or bad option.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo mountall`?

Comment: Let's continue this discussion in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/4495/help-for-user83303?tab=general)..

Comment: That command you posted returns ">" as if it is expecting input or something.

Comment: Oops! Fixed. :)

Comment: Also, I can't chat, not enough reputation :/

Comment: OK that command worked, but it's telling me the same thing. Partition identifier: /dev/sdb3
Mountpoint: /media/untitled

Comment: Ok.. try, then, `sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdb3 /media/untitled`. Also, make sure that `/media/untitled` actually exists!

Comment: I still get the not mounted or bad option message. This is getting frustrating haha. What do you mean make sure it exists?

Comment: Do `ls -la /media/` to list that directory's contents. The *untitled* folder should exists, for the partition to be mounted in there!

Comment: I have confirmed its existence! strangely it shows up as "drwxr-xr-x" doesn't that mean it should be read/write?

Comment: Yes, it should. Okay, now `ls -la /media/untitled`...

Comment: Two entries, both with the same permissions (what I listed above).

Comment: `sudo umount /media/untitled; sudo umount /dev/sdb3; sudo mount -o rw /dev/sdb3 /media/untitled; sudo mountall`

Comment: OK tried that. Firstly, after unmounting /media/untitled I got the message "/dev/sdb3: not mounted" after typing "umount /dev/sdb3". Typing "mount -o rw /dev/sdb3 /media/untitled" doesn't work because the mountpoint /media/untitled no longer exists, although I still see the "untitled" filesystem on my desktop.

Comment: `sudo mkdir /media/test-mountpoint; sudo mount /dev/sdb3 /media/test-mountpoint`

Comment: If only it were that easy! I got a warning after mounting which read "warning: /media/test-mountpoint/ seems to be mounted read-only.Back to square one :(

Comment: K, this should do it. `sudo umount /dev/sdb3; sudo umount /media/untitled; sudo rm -r /media/test-mountpoint; sudo apt-get install hfsprogs; sudo mount -t hfsplus -o force rw /dev/sdb3 /media/untitled`

Comment: No luck. The command didn't give me any errors or warnings, however I still can't write to the fs.

Comment: You can see your files though? If so, try `sudo chmod -R a+w /media/untitled` to give everyone write permissions on the files and folders on the volume. Note that you may want to think about this before actually doing it; I'm not responsible for any damage you cause to your (presumably) Mac partition.. :)

Comment: See which files? As of right now there is nothing on the fs, it's just an empty hfsplus partition I created. I'm gonna hold off for now on that, don't want to damage the fs. I'll speak with my supervisor about where to go from here. Thank you for all your help! Much appreciated :)

Comment: May I ask why you want to use **HFS+** as the filesystem? Anyway, see if you can `sudo touch /media/untitled/test.txt`

Comment: Cannot touch, Read-only file system. I'm creating a test image with a couple different filesystems to run some forensic tools against. Cool stuff :)

Comment: Ok, last try, after I give up :) `sudo mount -t hfsplus -o remount,rw,force /media/untitled`

Comment: Hmmm I don't think your last post was syntactically correct, it returned the usage for mount.

Comment: Grrr. `sudo mount -t hfsplus -o rw,remount -force /dev/sdb3 /media/untitled`

Comment: Tragically, it's still read-only.

Comment: Thanks again for all of your effort in trying to solve this!

Comment: I'd feel better if you're problem was solved! :)

Comment: Fixed it! dmesg revealed that it was not cleanly unmounted, then fsck fixed it.

Comment: Oh come on! That simple.. Good for you! :P In order to help clean up the site, please post the steps you took as an **answer** to your question and then **accept** your answer. This will prevent your questions from showing up in the *Unanswered* section. Thank you!

Comment: I know right? That's probably where I should have started. Oh well, at least it's fixed.

Comment: Yes! Now, please mark your your answer as **accepted**. This will prevent your questions from showing up in the *Unanswered* section. Thank you!

Comment: in case I am remounting as readonly, will this work with open files?

Comment: Does not work any of these by me, please check this, maybe you have an idea how to solve: http://askubuntu.com/questions/730822/cannot-mount-pendrive-in-write-mode

Comment: Sorry to revive an old thread... a recent 5-minute NAS problem caused an important partition to go into read-only mode in the middle of the night.  When I woke up I fixed it right away, but I effectively had a 5-hour service downtime. Is there any downside to having a script check every 5 minutes for read-only mode and try a remount automatically?

Comment: If that's fine, this produces a list of remount commands, but how would you actually execute this in a script?: `grep "^/" /proc/mounts | grep "\sro[\s,]" | awk '{print "mount -o remount,rw " $1 " " $2}'`

Comment: Can I remount my `/` filesystem as read-only for a few hours just for purposes of a `dd` backup to external drive?  Or does the system *always* need to be able to write to it's primary filesystem?

Comment: You don't need the partition. `mount -o remount,rw /mount/point` is sufficient.

Answer (score 60):

for busybox/android users:

> Oddly, I needed to *add* a space (in contrast to normal usage) between 'remount' and 'rw':

```
mount -o remount, rw /
```

otherwise it wouldn't work.

> UPDATE: it seems that this is almost never the case (see comments). Not sure which busybox-version + android-version I was running. I'll just leave this here in case anyone still runs into it.

Comment: I did *not* need an extra space on my Busybox implementation.  Or did you mean busybox *and* Android?  My busybox is within an embedded controller (not a smart phone)....

Comment: Had to do this on plain Ubuntu too.

Comment: what a strange syntax

Comment: @wallyk i found this out when I ssh'ed into my rooted android (busybox is a necessary app in the playstore). It might have been an old version of busybox, as it was android v2 dot something.

Comment: This worked for me... `mount -o remount,rw rootfs /` since my `/proc/mounts` has `rootfs / rootfs ro,seclabel,relatime 0 0`

Comment: I didn't need any space between `remount` and `rw`

Comment: I needed the extra space when I had a major typo in my /etc/fstab file preventing it from even running. I could not edit the /etc/fstab since my file system was in read-only. For some reason, when I ran 'mount -o remount,rw /' I would get this error: "/ not mounted or bad option". The only solution was to run your command with a extra space.

Answer (score 9):

Running `dmesg | grep hfs` showed that the filesystem was unmounted incorrectly, which I was able to repair using

```
fsck.hfsplus /dev/sdb3/
```

Answer (score 4):

First, let us fix NTFS problems (if you have an Ubuntu/Windows dual boot setup)

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda7
```

Before mounting we need a Directory (folder)

```
mkdir ~/Desktop/disk
```

Now mount the partition

```
sudo mount /dev/sda7 ~Desktop/disk
```

In this case "sda7" is the partition name.
Now you read from and write to the partition.

Answer (score 2):

I have **Dragonboard 410c**
I connecting via **adb**
I wanted to mount the physical sdcard as RW.
the following worked for me.

```
adb root
adb shell
su
mount -o remount,rw /storage/sdcard1   /storage/sdcard1
```

So I can now access it in rw mode as  **/storage/sdcard1**

nb. /storage/sdcard0 is emulated and is /sdcard

Answer (score 0):

First I typed mount to see the results and determine the mapping I wanted altered to full access was `/media/linux/OLD_PC`.

This worked fine to unlock the files and folders within my old Windows system partition.

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /media/linux/OLD_PC  /media/linux/OLD_PC
```