# How to remount a read-only folder as readWrite?

Tags: mount, read-only

Background:

I need to edit a file which is read only, and its parent folder is also read only. This file is located at a remote appliance. Through ssh I logged in to this as admin and I have the root access.

Command "ls -l" show the permissions of file as

```
"-rwxr-xr-x 1 admin root   952 Oct 30 02:01 file.sh"
```

and for folder

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 admin root
```

I am not as such familiar with Linux but I searched and found that these above lines mean that the admin is the owner and he/she has the read and write permission.

Someone suggested to remount the folder which contains this file.

Problem:

How will I remount it, I used

`mount -o remount,rw /folde1/folder2/targetFolder`

but It gave

`mount: can't find /folde1/folder2/targetFolder in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab`

I looked at question [How do I remount a filesystem as read/write?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175739/how-do-i-remount-a-filesystem-as-read-write), but I did not understand the answer...

It said correct syntax is

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /partition/identifier /mount/point
```

What should I give as  /partition/identifier and /mount/point? I.e. what is this /partition/identifier and /mount/point?

Comment: Partition identifier = the UUID or the device identifier, you can get this information for a particular partition by entering `sudo blkid` in your terminal. Mount point is the location where you'd like the partition to be mounted, usually `/media` or `/mnt`, you'll have to create a folder there and the location of that folder becomes the mount point.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Problem is solved, I remounted folder by using "mount -o remount,rw /" and then edited the file, without changing any permissions, it worked.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to remount anything. You must to change permissions. You can do it with this command:

```
sudo chmod 777 file.sh
```

This give all permisions to file, if you wish leave as read only for group and for rest of users you can do:

```
sudo chmod 644 file.sh
```

or

```
sudo chmod 755 file.sh
```

The first is for read-only, end the second for read and execute.

Comment: Thanks! :) I tried to change permissions but it was not working so someone told me to remount the folder. Problem is solved now, I used "mount -o remount,rw /", which remounted the folder and I edited the file, without changing permissions.

Comment: @user1204089 accept the answer so others doesn't have to try and solve it. Thanks!