# an error in .profile file prevents the system from booting?

Tags: login, permissions

I tryied to set the `JAVA_HOME` environmet variable in the `~/.profile` file
and I made a mistake

```
    JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_37"
    PATH=$JAVA_HOME:PATH
```

the error is in the `PATH` referencing. I put `PATH` rather than `$PATH`.
this prevents me from login.

I tried to edit the file using the recovery mode but it says that the file system is read only.
so any suggestions how to deal with this issue.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log in as another user that can sudo, or failing that start back up in resuce more, then before you edit the file remount the partition read write

`mount / -o remount -w` should work just fine.

[Take a look at this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175739/how-do-i-remount-a-filesystem-as-read-write) for more information on remounting.

Comment: Also X doesn't run .profile (I think) and you can start another shell via ssh  or use sftp to rename/edit the file is ssh is enabled.

Comment: I see the following as safer and hopefuly without a typo as above: `mount DEVICE -t FSTYPE -o remount -rw MOUNT_POINT` (whith DEVICE = e.g. `/dev/sdb2` and FSTYPE = e.g. `ext4`). Does its job on my Debian Wheezy (when forgetting the `t FSTYPE` would give a `mount: / not mounted or bad option`).

Answer (score 0):

Boot a live CD, mount the partition and edit the file (use sudo if you have to -- no password required).