# Auto upgrade failed to 20.04LTS, I deleted old kernels to save space and the latest one, now it thinks I am 20.04 when I'm not, help!

Tags: upgrade, kernel, 20.04

My computer asked me if I wanted to upgrade to 20.04LTS.  I said OK.   It filled up /boot and crashed.  I followed some instructions to boot into 2nd-to-last image and delete old kernels.  I did that, and deleted the newest kernel that crashed.  Then I did `sudo do-release-upgrade`.  It did nothing to the kernel, but now it thinks I have 20.04LTS.  I know I don't, because it should be a 5.4 kernel and what I have is

```
Linux catskills-Z390-AORUS-MASTER 5.3.0-62-generic #56-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 23 11:20:52 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I think I should have something like `5.4.0-26-generic`.  How do I get there safely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install the corresponding meta-package by:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic
```

and then to be completely sure install all newest dependencies for 20.04 LTS by

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Shouldn't the "upgrade" of Ubuntu have done this? If they offer an upgrade, it should work. Why is a manual intervention necessary?

Comment: Per the text of my question, it filled up the /boot partition with new stuff and then crashed in a horrible way.  I followed the suggested solution to get past the /boot fail.  That left it in a state where it thought it was 20.04 but was running an earlier kernel.  Hence the question.  See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/249135/booting-issues-after-crash-during-update