# How to edit xorg.conf if I loaded from flash drive?

Tags: nvidia, xorg

I upgraded my 12.04->12.10->13.04->13.10 had troubles with nVidia card and installed latest 331 nVidia driver from PPA after that ubuntu stopped loading at all. It won't load even in safemode. xorg.0.log says that it can't find display 0 or device 0 (not sure). However, loading from bootable stick works. But I can't find how can I edit /etc/X11/xorg.conf if I loaded from stick - it just won't let me do it.
What can I do in this situation?

Comment: As far as I remember there is no `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` on the live-CD. Question: Can you boot in recovery-mode (select-able in the grub)?

Comment: It gets up to grub, but won't load in failsafe configuration :(

Comment: And command-line mode loads in read-only. It it is possible to change read-only mounting at runtime that'd solve the issue.

Comment: "sudo mount -o remount,rw /" should do the trick. Also a bit related is [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/175739/how-do-i-remount-a-filesystem-as-read-write)

Comment: that worked, thank you! now I'm loaded in root mode and can modify xorg.conf, but it didn't help. I wanted to reinstall nvidia packages, but apparently I was able to uninstall, but not install, since somehow there is no network running. Is it possible to start network to connect to archives somehow?

Comment: Cool. But this really belongs into a new question.