# Fails to download respository Information check internet connection

Tags: apt, software-center

My Internet connection is working, but I cannot download anything from software center and I cannot update or upgrade from the terminal.

I changed my `/etc/apt/sources.list` to activate all the sources I have. None of them worked.

Comment: Which ubuntu version are you using? 14.04, or something older?

Comment: change the mirror server following this article: http://www.allfreeubuntu.tk/configure/

Comment: what are the errors when you are trying to update from a terminal?

Comment: Its 14.04 when i check for the best mirrorr it says check internet connection can't find suitable match and the errors are Err http://archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80] for all the different sources

Answer (score -1):

Do a backup of your `sources.list` file.

```
    cd /etc/apt/
    sudo cp sources.list sources.list.001  # if sources.list.001 doesn't exist
```

After generate a default set of sources e.g. from [Ubuntu Sources List Generator](http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/). Here you can select your release and country. Else
you can find on internet e.g. [here too](http://wiki.ubuntu-it.org/Repository/SourcesList).

Then copy it inside your `sources.list` file

```
    sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
                                     # Now paste the list, save and exit
    sudo apt-get update              # to resynchronize the package index 
                                     # files from their sources
    sudo apt-get -f install          # just in case you need to fix something
```

Now it would be possible to use the software centre too.

Comment: It should be useful the reason of the downvote to improve the answer or to limit its scope...