# apt-get stuck at 0 [Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com]

Tags: 14.04, command-line, apt, upgrade, updates

When I do upgrade it gets stuck here:

```
user@plato:~# sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  bind9-host coreutils cpio curl dnsutils libbind9-90 libc-bin libc-dev-bin
  libc6 libc6-dev libcgmanager0 libcurl3 libcurl3-gnutls libdns100
  libdrm-intel1 libdrm-nouveau2 libdrm-radeon1 libdrm2 libisc95 libisccc90
  libisccfg90 libjasper1 liblwres90 libplymouth2 libsepol1 libssl-dev
  libssl-doc libssl1.0.0 linux-libc-dev mime-support multiarch-support ntp
  ntpdate openssl plymouth plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text python3-distupgrade
  ubuntu-release-upgrader-core unzip
39 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 16.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 12.3 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
0% [Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (2001:67c:1562::15)] ░
```

When I do update it gets stuck here:

```
user@plato:~# apt-get update
0% [Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (2001:67c:1562::14)] [Connecting to sec░
```

I'm able to ping us.archive.ubuntu.com just fine:

```
user@plato:~# ping us.archive.ubuntu.com
PING us.archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.23) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from economy.canonical.com (91.189.91.23): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=81.5 ms
64 bytes from economy.canonical.com (91.189.91.23): icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=81.5 ms
64 bytes from economy.canonical.com (91.189.91.23): icmp_seq=3 ttl=54 time=81.5 ms
64 bytes from economy.canonical.com (91.189.91.23): icmp_seq=4 ttl=54 time=81.4 ms
^C
--- us.archive.ubuntu.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 81.425/81.528/81.582/0.355 ms
```

What can i do to fix this?

---

What I have tried so far.

I've tried following directions on this blog: http://nickescobedo.com/719/ubuntu-apt-get-hangs-at-0

To force apt-get to use IPv4 exclusively

- Create a file in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99force-ipv4`
- Add this line to newly created file `Acquire::ForceIPv4 false;`
- Apt-get will now use IPv4 exclusively

Comment: None of the answers worked for me: my problem was my Windows host **firewall** blocking my Ubuntu guest running in Virtualbox.

Comment: None of these answers worked for me. I restarted my virtual machine and it works now.

Answer (score 341, accepted):

I figured out how to get apt-get to work again.

Edit [`gai.conf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/gai.conf.5):

```
sudo vim /etc/gai.conf
```

change line ~54 to uncomment the following:

```
precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  100
```

write and quit:

```
:wq
```

---

#### CAUTION

Look out line 50 which looks almost identical:

```
precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  10
```

This is the wrong line. Go ~4 lines down and you'll find the correct line to uncomment because it ends with `100` instead of `10`

Comment: Thank you for posting your solution. I was having the same issue and this fixed it.

Comment: How on Earth did you figure this out? This suddenly started happening to me on one of my servers and this fixed it.

Comment: When this happened to me, I thought I'll need an eternity to figure what is going on. Got this solution as first hit and directly solved it....less than 5 minutes! Still would like to know why this happened in the first place, though. (The solution gives some hints to the cause, but not much)

Comment: It just happened to me after an update from the software center. Something must have changed it. Totally appreciate the answer, +1 for saving me hours of pain.

Comment: Huge thank you, this saved me hours of contacting support and pain.

Comment: How is it even possible that this happens? I even did a clean Ubuntu install when this happened.

Comment: What is going on here? Care to elaborate why this fix works?

Comment: **Problem:** ISPs are starting to setup an internal IPv6 network in preparation for eventually connecting to the IPv6 internet. As a result, servers in this network now try to connect to *.ubuntu.com via its IPv6 address by default when running apt-get. **Solution:** uncommenting `precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  100` allows requests to prefer IPv4

Comment: FIXED! This is definitely the right fix for this issue. But for anyone that comes across this fix make sure you DO NOT do what I did. I uncommented `precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  10` and I had to go back in to the file and comment that line again and then uncomment the correct line which is `precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  100`

Comment: Nothing better than a magic solution that works as the first Google hit.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I was wondering why I couldn't update any packages over my phone's tethered internet connection. I wonder how long it will take until Verizon fixes their IPv6?

Comment: In addition to the `precedence` fix, I had to append `dns-nameservers 8.8.4.4 8.8.8.8` to the end of /etc/network/interfaces. http://askubuntu.com/questions/766131/set-static-ip-ubuntu-16-04. My ISP is monkeybrains.net.

Comment: This did not work for me, this did: http://askubuntu.com/a/759540/4246

Comment: Classic. I wish the ISPs wouldn't roll out IPv6 until they have it really working. I had to disable IPv6 on my computer because my home Comcast connection had issues with routing to Google and Facebook.

Comment: Is there a link to some extended explanation about why this happened?

Comment: Man, you just solved me sooo many issues:D

Comment: You, sir, are a genius.

Comment: This fix worked for me, then I saw the comment about home internet and realized that google and only google takes forever to connect as well. Checked facebook and it has the same problem so I disabled IPv6 (see link if you need to do the same) and now they work great. Why does this only create problems for these sites? https://askubuntu.com/questions/440649/how-to-disable-ipv6-in-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: I solved this by changing all sources in `/etc/apt/sources.list` to `https`.  You'll need `apt-transport-https` first and to use a mirror that supports https (i.e. `deb https://ubuntu.osuosl.org/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted`).

Comment: Wow...thanks for the solution. Works like a charm

Comment: Thank you! This also solved my issue. Have a local server in my house as someone pointed out above this is an IPS issue/feature...

Comment: WTF ! What sorcery is this !!! Worked like magic . Upvoted !

Comment: ???? ARE YOU A WIZARD?

Answer (score 19):

It's better to disable the IPV6 before you update and upgrade.

1. Open Terminal
2. Enter `sudo -H gedit /etc/sysctl.conf` and open the configuration file and add the following lines at the end

   ```
   net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
   net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1 
   net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
   ```
3. After that run

   ```
   cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
   ```

   If it reports ‘1′ means you have disabled IPV6.

   If it reports ‘0‘ then please follow Step 4 and Step 5.
4. Type command `sudo sysctl -p`. You will see this in terminal.

   ```
   net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1 
   net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1 
   net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
   ```
5. Repeat above “Step 3” and it will now report 1.

Comment: this worked.I did not understand why. Can you explain please.

Answer (score 9):

None of the IPv6 fixes worked for me. Possibly I have the same symptom with a different cause. My workaround was to switch to a different archive by doing a search and replace in sources.list, e.g.:

```
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list
```

And then:

```
:%s/us\.archive/de\.archive/g
:wq
```

This at least allows me to get back to work until I figure out the real problem.

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was to switch my VirtualBox Network settings for my Ubuntu guest to "NAT" from "Bridged Adapter".

Comment: Yes, this is bound to work. But, why doesn't it work over 'Bridged Adapter'. I am able to do everything with 'Bridged Adapter' except `apt-get update`.