# Installed Ubuntu 14.04 with interesting boot options and now it's black screen instead of GUI

Tags: drivers, nvidia

Installed Ubuntu 14.04 with acpi=off, nolapic, and nomodeset to get it to skirt around my discreet graphics card only to find it running super slow. The frame rate was terrible. So I decided to install vvidia drivers. I downloaded the .run and made it executable with chmod. It wouldn't let me start it with X server running so I terminated that process. Boom, GUI gone. I did some weird trickery to get it back. I'll include the links of the different places I took advice from:

[apt-get stuck at 0 [Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/574569/apt-get-stuck-at-0-connecting-to-us-archive-ubuntu-com)
[Blank screen after installing nvidia restricted driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41681/blank-screen-after-installing-nvidia-restricted-driver)

There are a few others but those are the major ones. I'm totally new at this. But I'm committed and I want to learn linux. I just don't know the right commands to rebuild my GUI and properly install my video card. It took me FOREVER to get it installed in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to waste your time installing it from source. Those drivers are available (as most software is) directly from the Ubuntu repositories precompiled and optimized for your version of Ubuntu.

You can log into a text session at any time by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> or you can use  <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F3</kbd>, <kbd>F4</kbd> whatever.

Sign in with your username and password and then, execute the following commands to get started:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now, you can choose to install it from apt-get with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia nvidia-updates
```

when you are done with install, reboot.

Comment: the first command worked but the second, I get this:

Package nvidia is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source.

E: Package 'nvidia' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package nvidia-updates

Comment: I just decided to start from scratch and reinstall. Now it's giving me problems again reinstalling. It hangs on the black screen with the cursor blinking and nothing happens. The disk drive has no activity.

Comment: @JZN Aw, you should've just ran `apt-cache search nvidia | grep nvidia` to output a the specific packages that are available. It probably would've just been `nvidia-updates` without asking for the one it complained about. I'll change that anyway. Next time you get it installed, immediately go to the Ubuntu Software Center, click "Edit" and select Software Sources, Click on the "extra drivers" tab and wait a few seconds for it to detect your hardware and it will show a list of compatable and available drivers for your nvidia hardware both proprietary (from nvidia) and opensource (nouveau) drive

Comment: @JZN . . . should be listed. The best bet will be to go with the version listed as "proprietary tested" and it will both install and configure the brand name nvidia drivers automatically for you after making the selection. You should open another question for the installation problem to receive the fastest help for that issue.