# Apt-get upgraded package from 32bit to unsupported 64bit - why and how to revert?

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, 64-bit, architecture

Recently the repository of `qtox` had to change its domain and the new one only contains only 64bit builds at the moment. However, I'm on 15.04 32bit and can't run any 64bit software.

Now when I last ran `apt-get upgrade` or `apt-get dist-upgrade` (can't remember which one exactly), it also upgraded the package `qtox` to the latest version in the repository. *But this was a 64 bit version!* Now I can't launch `qtox` any more:

```
$ qtox
bash: /usr/bin/qtox: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
$ file $(which qtox)
/usr/bin/qtox: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, stripped
$ uname -a
Linux UbuntuDesktop 3.19.0-26-generic #27-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 28 18:26:33 UTC 2015 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Now I have to make sure that `apt-get` will not install/upgrade to any 64bit packages any more! No idea if this is a bug in `apt-get`, a badly configured package or repository or anything else, I need to find out the cause and prevent this from happening again!

So my question in a nutshell:

**Why did `apt-get` install a 64bit package on a 32bit-only system and how do I avoid this in the future?**

---

#### Update:

I checked the info I could get about the `qtox` package from `apt-cache` and `dpkg -I` of the directly downloaded .deb package and found the following. It seems to me like if the had configured their repository incorrectly, because those outputs look like of a 32bit package. And it still contains the old domain. Did they probably forget to update their info and cheated on `apt-get`?

```
$ apt-cache show qtox
Package: qtox
Priority: extra
Section: default
Installed-Size: 2168
Maintainer: Tox Foundation <support@tox.im>
Architecture: i386
Version: 1.1~git20150707.cfeeb03-97
Replaces: qtox-unity
Depends: libopenal1, libqt5core5a, libqt5gui5, libqt5network5, libqt5widgets5, libqt5xml5, libqt5opengl5, libqt5sql5, libqt5sql5-sqlite, apt-transport-https, libqt5svg5, libappindicator1, libqrencode3, libavformat-ffmpeg56|libavformat-tox56, libavdevice-ffmpeg56|libavdevice-tox56, libavcodec-ffmpeg56|libavcodec-tox56, libavutil-ffmpeg54|libavutil-tox54, libswscale-ffmpeg3|libswscale-tox3
Filename: pool/main/q/qtox/qtox_1.1~git20150707.cfeeb03-97_i386.deb
Size: 2217972
MD5sum: bc59427d056da669e52955169266911b
SHA1: c6797a04d13d929a068c213913f359719b377735
SHA256: 3405027807573b98a61c33f3aad911f40cf0b0737a95001e951a82937ee5afdd
Description: no description given
Description-md5: c0af8b65ef8df63b3bfb124d96da1778
Homepage: https://tox.im
Vendor: Tox Foundation
License: GPLv3+

$ apt-cache policy qtox
qtox:
  Installed: 1.1~git20150707.cfeeb03-97
  Candidate: 1.1~git20150707.cfeeb03-97
  Version table:
 *** 1.1~git20150707.cfeeb03-97 0
        500 https://pkg.tox.chat/ nightly/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

$  dpkg -I qtox_1.1~git20150707.cfeeb03-97_i386.deb
 new debian package, version 2.0.
 size 2217972 bytes: control archive=2341 bytes.
     677 bytes,    13 lines      control              
    1298 bytes,    17 lines      md5sums              
    2716 bytes,    93 lines   *  postinst             #!/bin/sh
 Package: qtox
 Version: 1.1~git20150707.cfeeb03-97
 License: GPLv3+
 Vendor: Tox Foundation
 Architecture: i386
 Maintainer: Tox Foundation <support@tox.im>
 Installed-Size: 2168
 Depends: libopenal1, libqt5core5a, libqt5gui5, libqt5network5, libqt5widgets5, libqt5xml5, libqt5opengl5, libqt5sql5, libqt5sql5-sqlite, apt-transport-https, libqt5svg5, libappindicator1, libqrencode3, libavformat-ffmpeg56|libavformat-tox56, libavdevice-ffmpeg56|libavdevice-tox56, libavcodec-ffmpeg56|libavcodec-tox56, libavutil-ffmpeg54|libavutil-tox54, libswscale-ffmpeg3|libswscale-tox3
 Replaces: qtox-unity
 Section: default
 Priority: extra
 Homepage: https://tox.im
 Description: no description given
```

Comment: **After the tox repository maintainers changed the repo structure again, now the current 32bit binary package is working again without issues!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously the package's name and meta information both tell `apt-get` that it is a 32bit package, but this was set up falsely by the maintainers.

Until they have fixed this and updated their repository with a real 32bit package, I use the following script to verify the package's true architecture:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash

dir=$(mktemp -d)
debfile="*_i386.deb"
cd "$dir"

echo "Downloading package..."
wget https://pkg.tox.chat/pool/main/q/qtox/ -r -l 1 -nd -A "$debfile" -q

dpkg -x $debfile "$dir"
printf "\n%s\n\n" $debfile

dpkg --info $debfile | \
    awk '/Architecture/ {printf "defined dpkg architecture is:\t%s\n", $2}'

find "$dir" -type f -exec file -b {} \; | \
        sort -u | \
        awk '/ELF/ {printf "real executable format is: \t\t%s\n", $0}'

rm -rf "$dir"
exit 0
```

<sub>(Parts of the script are taken from **A.B.**'s answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/660936/367990).)</sub>

I saved it as `~/bin/qtoxtest.sh` and made it executable with `chmod +x ~/bin/qtoxtest.sh`.

The script currently gives the following example output, which tells us that the package is still not correctly declared:

```
$  qtoxtest.sh 
Downloading package...

qtox_1.1~git20150707.cfeeb03-97_i386.deb

defined dpkg architecture is:   i386
real executable format is:      ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, stripped
```

Comment: **The script does not work any more, because the tox repository's directory structure changed and therefore the download address became invalid. But the good news: The new 32bit package is a real 32bit package and works as expected!**