# Connecting PC and RaspberryPi using LAN cable

Tags: networking, ssh, raspberrypi, lan

I am trying to connect my desktop running Ubuntu 16.04 to a Raspberry Pi3 running Ubuntu MATE. The end goal is to ssh using Ethernet connection by assigning static IP addresses to PC (say 10.0.0.1) and to Pi (say 10.0.0.2).

Then I can do `ssh pi@10.0.0.2` from the PC, right?. I have connected PC and Pi using ethernet/lan cable. Then I disabled `Enable Wi-Fi` option on Raspberry Pi and I can see that it is connected to Wired Connection 1. Running `ifconfig` command on the Raspberry Pi gives:

```
pi@pi-desktop:~$ ifconfig 
enxb827eb3d64cc Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:3d:64:cc  
              inet addr:192.168.100.1  Bcast:192.168.100.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
              inet6 addr: fe80::afe3:308f:92f3:e890/64 Scope:Link
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:662 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:111 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
              RX bytes:151040 (151.0 KB)  TX bytes:19190 (19.1 KB)
    
    lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
              inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
              inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
              UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
              RX packets:21628 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:21628 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
              RX bytes:1300280 (1.3 MB)  TX bytes:1300280 (1.3 MB)
```

Then I was planning to set PCs IP address to 192.168.100.2 but it is not connected to Wired Connection 1 even with `Enable Wi-Fi` disabled. Running `ifconfig` on PC gives:

```
pc@pc-desk:~$ ifconfig
enp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:d4:35:d1:2c:f4  
          inet6 addr: fe80::181f:fbbb:63d2:c4e4/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:106 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1386 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:17736 (17.7 KB)  TX bytes:263114 (263.1 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:9695 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9695 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:845799 (845.7 KB)  TX bytes:845799 (845.7 KB)
```

I am stuck here. Any pointers would be highly appreciated.

#### Edit: Output of ethtool

On PC:

```
pc@pc-desk:~$ ethtool enp3s0

    Settings for enp3s0:
        Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
        Supported pause frame use: No
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                             100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
        Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Speed: 100Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: MII
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
    Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: Operation not permitted
        Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                       drv probe ifdown ifup
        Link detected: yes
```

On Raspberry Pi :

```
pi@pi-desktop:~$ ethtool enxb827eb3d64cc
Settings for enxb827eb3d64cc:
    Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                         100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
    Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 100Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: MII
    PHYAD: 1
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: Operation not permitted
    Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                   drv probe link
    Link detected: yes
```

Output of `uname -a` command:

On Raspberry Pi:

```
pi@pi-desktop:~$ uname -a
Linux pi-desktop 4.4.38-v7+ #938 SMP Thu Dec 15 15:22:21 GMT 2016 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
```

On PC:

```
pc@pc-desk:~$ uname -a
Linux pc-desk 4.13.0-26-generic #29~16.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 9 22:00:44 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: ...and you have to configure both sides to the static IP addresses you intent to use. You can do that temporarily (not reboot safe) with `ifconfig enp3s0 10.0.0.2 netmask 255.255.255.0 up`(or whatever range you have decided to use, just make sure they are in the same range)

Comment: Yes , you are right. I forgot to change the IP to static address before posting the ifconfig output of raspberry pi.  I usually set static IPs using GUI under network connections->Edit connections->IPv4 settings. I can see 10.0.0.2 and 255.255.255.0 as ip and subnet mask, what should the gateway be set to in this case ? . In normal cases I would set it to router IP address

Comment: I have added the output . I could not make much sense of it though.

Comment: It worked!. I think like you mentioned the error occurred since the static IPs were not set.  I was under the assumption that if ifconfig doesnot list IP address then it is not connected to the network. Thank you for your response. Can you post the above comments as answer. I can accept it then . Cheers :)

Comment: lets_try and @user68186, I've added my answer and as soon as it is accepted we can clean up the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to *configure both sides with the static IP addresses* you intent to use.

The `ifconfig` output for the PC tells me that the interface is not *up* and no IP is configured - we have to remedy that.

To cover our bases you should make sure your cabling is fine, you can do that with `ethtool` on both sides

```
sudo apt-get install ethtool
```

then on the Pi:

```
ethtool enxb827eb3d64cc
```

and on the PC:

```
ethtool enp3s0
```

Look for

```
Link detected: yes
```

and make sure that *speed* and *duplex* are the same on both sides, with a Pi it should look like

```
Speed: 100Mb/s
Duplex: Full
```

Now you can change your IPs temporarily (not reboot safe) with

```
ifconfig enp3s0 10.0.0.2 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

on the PC and the following on the Pi

```
ifconfig enxb827eb3d64cc 10.0.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

No gateway needed since they are both in the same network.

A permanent solution would be to set the IPs either in the GUI or in the config file called `/etc/network/interfaces`.

This depends heavily on the GUI you use but something similar to

```
Preferences -> Connections->Edit connections->IPv4 settings
```

should be it on both the PC and the Pi

[Here is a good example](https://askubuntu.com/a/784079/783023) of how to set a static IP. Just keep in mind that you may have to disable the GUIs network settings (i.e. gnome's **Network Manager** tends to overwrite and override this unless disabled)

(or whatever range you have decided to use, just make sure they are in the same range)

Answer (score 3):

### On the Ubuntu Desktop

**Note: This is for Ubuntu desktop. The interface for Mate may be different**

1. On the computer, which is connected to the Internet, click the network icon in the panel and go to *"Edit Connections..."* at the bottom of the menu.

   [image: Edit Connection...]
2. Double click your **Wired Connection** (Leave your wireless connection untouched, the one connected to Internet and the one you want to share, as I understand).

   [image: Network Connections Dialog]
3. On the *"IPv4 Settings tab"*, select Method: *"Shared to other computers"*

   [image: Editing Wired Connection]
4. Reconnect by clicking on the *Wired Network*, so it gets a new IP address. (The two computers must be connected by an ethernet cable for this step, so connect them now if you haven't already.)
5. Click on *"Connection Information"* in the network menu and write down the IP address and network mask (in my case it was assigned 10.42.0.1/255.255.255.0 but I do not know if that will always be the case).

   [image: Connection Information]

### On the Raspberry Pi

**Assign static IP to the Ethernet connection**

1. In Pi the WiFi device is called wlan but the ethernet device name is hard to guess. To find the device names use the command:

   $ ip link show

The output will show your Ethernet device in Pi `enxb827eb3d64cc`

2. Next we need to find the current IP addresses assigned to
   `enxb827eb3d64cc`:

   $ ip -4 addr show dev enxb827eb3d64cc | grep inet

I get something like this, yours may be different:

```
inet 10.42.0.211/24 brd 10.42.0.255 scope global enxb827eb3d64cc
```

3. You can keep the assigned IP address or choose a different one in the same subnet. Add the following lines at the end of  /etc/dhcpcd.conf by:

   $ sudo nano /etc/dhcpcd.conf

With the following content to make the assigned IP address static:

```
# Custom static IP address for enxb827eb3d64cc
interface enxb827eb3d64cc
static ip_address=10.42.0.211/24
static routers=10.42.0.255
static domain_name_servers=10.42.0.255
```

Change `10.42.0.211` above to `10.42.0.x` where x is a number between 2 and 254 if you want to assign a different IP address.

4. Reboot Pi to make the new IP address take effect:

   $ sudo reboot now

Now you should be able to `ssh` from the desktop to the Pi with the following command:

```
$ ssh pi@10.42.0.211
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your response. I accepted Robert Riedl's since it was the first correct answer to my problem and just to be fair :)