# problem with ip changing in ubuntu

Tags: networking, ip

There is a problem when I set up my server system ,IP would be different when I use Wired network connection and wireless network connection，how can I set unchanging IP when I connect to the system? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly. Could you please confirm whether the system in question (1) has two network interfaces active at the same time (2) that have different IP addresses and (3) you want to send packages through *both* of them in parallel using the same IP address? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The prior answer assumes you're talking about external IP address; which is set by ISP. I take your question as asking about the LAN IP address; which can be changed in many ways.

[Set static IP Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766131/set-static-ip-ubuntu-16-04)

On my own ubuntu 16.04LTS (running XFCE so think Xubuntu) I can 'click' the network icon on top of my left monitor and view "Network Connections"; A dynamic (changing, or set by router) uses DHCP (d=dynamic) which just needs to be changed and you're done. You can do it this way if you prefer; using your current addresses as a guide. Keeping wireless as DHCP may be worthwhile (it'll likely work in more locations)