# Wired connection is not working | Xubuntu 16.04.3 lts

Tags: networking, xubuntu

I am new to Linux and currently using xubuntu 16.04.3 with some asus laptop.

I am trying to connect to the internet through a router in my dorm room. Wi-fi works without a fuss however I couldn't manage to get wired connection to work.

I guess I am supposed to configure my network with an address, mask and gateway given to me from the university. I did so, both through network-manager's "edit connection" tab and through /etc/network/interfaces to no avail. 
I even deleted network manager and tried to set up my network from scratch (it was a complete failure, at least with nm I've got my wi fi working).

I have a Realtek RTL8101 Ethernet controller with the latest drivers installed.

```
-network 
description: Ethernet interface
product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
physical id: 0.2
bus info: pci@0000:01:00.2
logical name: enp1s0f2
version: 06
serial: 
size: 100Mbit/s
capacity: 100Mbit/s
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8101 driverversion=1.032.04-NAPI duplex=half latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
resources: irq:282 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:91214000-91214fff memory:91210000-91213fff
```

and here are some other identifications

```
ozzy@ozan-E402NA:~$ nmcli device
DEVICE TYPE STATE CONNECTION 
wlp2s0 wifi connected Ozanoz 
enp1s0f2 ethernet unavailable -- 
lo loopback unmanaged --


ozzy@ozan-E402NA:~$ dmesg | grep enp1s0f2
[ 2.453500] r8101 0000:01:00.2 enp1s0f2: renamed from eth0
[ 7.072185] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp1s0f2: link is not ready
[ 7.072589] enp1s0f2: 0xffffad7dc06a9000, 10:7b:3c:8f:3c:8f, IRQ 282
[ 7.196282] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp1s0f2: link is not ready
```

and lastly ifconfig

```
enp1s0f2 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 
UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
Interrupt:26 Base address:0x9000 

lo Link encap:Local Loopback 
inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:65536 Metric:1
RX packets:580 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:580 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
RX bytes:48025 (48.0 KB) TX bytes:48025 (48.0 KB)

wlp2s0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 
inet addr:192.168.43.225 Bcast:192.168.43.255 Mask:255.255.255.0
inet6 addr: fe80::f90a:83a2:8b5b:65f9/64 Scope:Link
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
RX packets:5972 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:5879 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
RX bytes:4259264 (4.2 MB) TX bytes:1498181 (1.4 MB)
```

Well, I am completely lost and couldn't figure out a possible solution and need your help.

Have a good day/night.

Ozan

p.s. I am going to sleep now, and I won't be able to reply to your messages for some time. see you tomorrow...

Comment: Related:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/766131/set-static-ip-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: @Terrance I have tried and tried similar changes in /interfaces but it didn't work but I will try yet again first thing in the morning. Thanks for the reply.