# How do you set up a static address using /etc/networks/interfaces

Tags: networking

I want to set up a static IP address using `/etc/network/interfaces`. How can I do that?

Comment: Is your setup a desktop ubuntu or a server ubuntu?

Comment: Which Ubuntu version do you use? What have you tried so far? Please [edit] your question to include the details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set static IP Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766131/set-static-ip-ubuntu)

Answer (score 3):

I'm just gonna quote [this great article](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/setting-up-an-network-interfaces-file/):

> Defining physical interfaces such as eth0
>
> Lines beginning with the word “auto” are used to identify the physical interfaces to be brought up when ifup is run with the -a option. (This option is used by the system boot scripts.) Physical interface names should follow the word “auto” on the same line. There can be multiple “auto” stanzas. ifup brings the named inter faces up in the order listed. For example following example setup eth0 (first network interface card) with 192.168.1.5 IP address and gateway (router) to 192.168.1.254:

```
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.5
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.254
```

> Setup interface to dhcp
>
> To setup eth0 to dhcp, enter:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

If you're new to Ubuntu, or Linux in general, I recommend you bookmark that site. He has a lot of great articles and tutorials that will help you out.