# Set temporary static IP in ubuntu 18 without editing files

Tags: networking, 18.04

I have a USB network interface which I want to set the IP address and netwmask on manually. If I do that this way:

```
$ sudo ip addr add 10.1.1.1/24 dev eno1
```

I also run this:

```
$ nmcli dev set eno1 managed no  
$ nmcli dev
DEVICE           TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION             
eno1             ethernet  unmanaged     --
```

But then after a variable amount of time (usually less than a minute) the IP address will be lost. If I run `nmcli dev` again, I see that it has again become a managed interface:

```
$ nmcli dev
DEVICE           TYPE      STATE                                  CONNECTION         
eno1             ethernet  connecting (getting IP configuration)  Wired connection 2
```

I've read answers like [Set static IP Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766131/set-static-ip-ubuntu) which require editing a file. I don't want to make this change permanent, so how can I set a static IP via command-line only, no file editing?

Comment: Is the behavior improved if you stop Network Manager? `sudo service network-manager stop` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: No, stopping network manager does not change the behavior.