# How to get DNS working after install of 19.04 using static IP

Tags: network-manager, dns

After installing Kubuntu 19.04, DNS stopped working after setting static IP address. Am able to successfully ping gateway address but name resolution does not work. Setting interface back to DHCP (automatic) and DNS starts working. Set interface back to static IP (manual) and DNS resolution stops. This suggests there might be a problem in the Network Manager configuration code. Where are the DNS server addresses stored nowadays? With Network Manager, Systemd, NetPlan etc. it's almost impossible to debug these types of problems. I've reviewed similar questions going back to 2006 but they don't pertain anymore as things have changed and their recommendations don't work anymore.

Static IP was set using Network Manager using the Edit Network Connections graphical dialog and yes, I set the nameserver addresses in the dialog. I assume, that once you click "apply" and "ok" those addresses get written somewhere. Question is, Where?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/766131/how-do-i-set-a-static-ip-in-ubuntu

Comment: @AndréSilva-PT That circa-2016 answer is no longer valid for Ubuntu 19.04. Sorry.

Comment: Where and how did you set your static IP details? Network Manager? Did you also specify DNS nameservers?

Comment: use `systemd-resolve --status` to check DNS, it is also used to set DNS manually

Comment: If the real purpose of this post is to get me to upgrade to Ubuntu 19, it is working

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1159084/make-dns-follow-configuration-from-network-manager-in-19-04/1159255?noredirect=1#comment1930213_1159255

Comment: I don't want to go and change the methodology just to get it to work because at the next upgrade it could undo the changes I made and it stops working again. If I use Network Manager GUI to define the IP and DNS servers, where does that information get written? Why isn't this documented somewhere or if it is, why is it so hard to find?