# Cannot ping GitHub

Tags: networking, dns, ping, github

I cannot access to [GitHub](https://github.com) only on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine and all other machines (Windows PC, iPad, Phone) connected to the same network can access GitHub.

When I try to ping GitHub, I get

[image: result of ping github.com]

The result of run `nslookup github.com`:

```
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   github.com
Address: 192.30.253.112
```

If I try `sudo route -n`:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.178.1   0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp4s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp4s0
192.168.178.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp4s0
```

If I `ping google.com`, it works.

I can't access GitHub in the browser also. However, all other websites work fine. Also, I can access GitHub on other devices. Is there anything wrong with the DNS?

Comment: There is something wrong with the IP address. When I lookup github.com the IP is 140.82.113.4.  It looks like that you may have a DNS problem.

Comment: @NK_ When I typed in the IP you gave (140.82.113.4) in the browser, I noticed the address was redirected to github.com. And same to the IP address I provided (192.30.253.112), the address was also redirected to github.com. The only problem is that the site "can't be reached", so I would say the IP address is correct. It's different just because that different DNS resolve the address of github.com differently according to the location.

Comment: Looks like you are correct joeller. Do you mean you cannot access both 140.82.113.4 and 192.30.253.112 on your browser? Just a little possibility, but maybe enabling location services might help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got exactly same problem below is how I solve it :
In short : there might be a github.com mistakenly configured in

> ```
> /etc/hosts
> ```

```
Please comment out item below , everything works right for me  
# Github
#192.30.253.113 github.com
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62964265/cannot-ping-github-on-ubuntu1804-suspect-network-configration-issue/62964372#62964372

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much @Jia. That solved my problem!!!

Comment: Fixed for me as well, +1

Comment: I'm having the same random issue on ubuntu 20...

Answer (score 0):

Doing a reverse DNS lookup on the IP address posted in the question, reveals that this points to a DNS server with hostname `dns1.p07.nsone.net` rather than `github.com`.

```
$ dig -x 192.30.253.112

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1-Debian <<>> -x 192.30.253.112
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 48141
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;112.253.30.192.in-addr.arpa.   IN      PTR

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
253.30.192.in-addr.arpa. 3600   IN      SOA     dns1.p07.nsone.net. hostmaster.nsone.net. 1591647771 43200 7200 1209600 3600

;; Query time: 41 msec
;; SERVER: REDACTED#53(REDACTED)
;; WHEN: Sat Jul 18 16:59:59 CST 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 121
```

In other words, this is a DNS problem.  How to resolve the issue ?

- attempt changing your nameserver (there are plenty of public nameservers to choose from, such as Google DNS 8.8.8.8, OpenDNS 206.67.220.220, Level 3 209.244.0.3, and others). There are several ways depending on your Ubuntu release. For the most recent ones,  that can be done via [`netplan` settings](https://askubuntu.com/a/767693/295286)
- If 192.30.253.112 is your ISP's nameserver, report the issue to their technical support so that the issue can be fixed on their end

Answer (score -1):

Your dns server is pointed to a loopback, therefore your own machine.
You can change the dns servers by doing the following:

```
nano /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
```

Under nameservers then addresses enter this:

```
  nameservers:
      addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
```

Run this to apply the changes:

```
sudo netplan apply
```

Then to verify the changes have been made run this:

```
systemd-resolve --status | grep 'DNS Servers' -A2
```

Comment: Thanks Jack! I tried to modified the DNS server as you replied. But I still can't ping and access GitHub. If the DNS server is pointed to a loopback as you said, then all sites can't be reached by the URL. But in my case the only thing wrong is GitHub.

Comment: Have you tried clearing your dns cache?

Comment: Yes, I tried that.