# how to solve curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection reset by peer in connection to raw.githubusercontent.com:443 error?

Tags: networking, command-line, bash

I am trying to install the Homebrew package on my system but whenever I try to run the below command to install homebrew I am getting the above-mentioned error
Command to install homebrew:

```
./bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

How can I solve this error?
I am using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS OS
OS Type: 64 bit

Comment: You should first check whether your server can connect to github or not, check the output using this: `curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh`

Comment: No I cannot connect my server to github I checked it by running ping github.com command how can I fix it?

Comment: This belongs to network problem and can have many aspects. You can troubleshoot this by checking these points: 1.  DNS issues. 2. firewall or proxy issues. 3. HTTP proxy configuration issues. 4. GitHub accessibility issues. 5. you can try using a site that supports accelerated GitHub downloads, such as GitClone. you can get refer from [here-cannot ping GitHub.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1254542/cannot-ping-github)

Answer (score 0):

I read some stack exchange question which were related to my question to resolve this issue I found a hack to use VPN . In ubuntu snap store you can use Riseup VPN to solve this issue. In this scenario, router seems to be doing a transparent proxy.

If it is, then you may want to turn that off.

If you can't turn it off, then you might want to install a VPN solution that will allow you to bypass it.

You can go through this [stackExchange](https://superuser.com/questions/1264498/homebrew-gives-ssl-error-ssl-error-syscall-on-home-network?_gl=1*4n4eed*_ga*NjYwNzk5NTYyLjE2Nzc5OTA1ODM.*_ga_S812YQPLT2*MTY3Nzk5MDU4My4xLjEuMTY3Nzk5MTEwMi4wLjAuMA..) question for more:

Answer (score 0):

Adding `--resolve raw.githubusercontent.com:443:185.199.108.133` after `curl` will solve the issue.

**For example:**

In the above case instead of

```
./bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

do

```
./bin/bash -c "$(curl --resolve raw.githubusercontent.com:443:185.199.108.133 -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```