# How to configure static IP address on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS from GUI interface?

Tags: 16.04, ethernet, interface, static-ip

How to configure static IP address on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS from GUI interface?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set static IP address?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/338442/how-to-set-static-ip-address) or [How do I set a static IP in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766131/how-do-i-set-a-static-ip-in-ubuntu)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set a static IP in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766131/how-do-i-set-a-static-ip-in-ubuntu)

Comment: @Nmath Yes, it helped. Although, I already tried this before, but for some reason setting IPv4 Settings addresses from GUI wasn't successful.