# Directory "/proc/sys/net/" missing in Ubuntu 14.04.4 on Windows

Tags: 14.04, networking, windows, directory, proc

I have been trying to trouble-shoot connectivity issues with Bash on Ubuntu on Windows (Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS), and I discovered I don't have a `/proc/sys/net` directory.

```
me@mycomp:~$ ll -a /proc/sys/
total 0
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Dec 15 14:41 ./
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Dec 15 14:41 ../
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Dec 15 14:41 kernel/
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Dec 15 14:41 vm/
```

Is this normal? How do I create one with the appropriate contents?

.

I do have a /proc/net directory, which links to `/proc/self/net/`. Not sure if that's relevant.

```
me@mycomp:~$ ll -a /proc/net
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Dec 15 14:41 /proc/net -> self/net/
me@mycomp:~$ ll -a /proc/self/net/
total 0
dr-xr-xr-x 1 eflynn90 eflynn90 0 Dec 15 15:33 ./
dr-xr-xr-x 1 eflynn90 eflynn90 0 Dec 15 15:33 ../
-r--r--r-- 1 root     root     0 Dec 15 15:33 if_inet6
-r--r--r-- 1 root     root     0 Dec 15 15:33 netlink
-r--r--r-- 1 root     root     0 Dec 15 15:33 tcp
-r--r--r-- 1 root     root     0 Dec 15 15:33 tcp6
-r--r--r-- 1 root     root     0 Dec 15 15:33 udp
-r--r--r-- 1 root     root     0 Dec 15 15:33 udp6
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root     root     0 Dec 15 15:33 xt_qtaguid/
```

(For those curious, my connectivity issues include [`apt-get` stalling on "Connecting..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/574569/apt-get-stuck-at-0-connecting-to-us-archive-ubuntu-com) and [`ssh` saying resource temporarily unavailable](https://superuser.com/questions/1098526/windows-10-linux-subsystem-ssh-client-resource-temporarily-unavailable).)