# Keyserver timeout when trying to add key

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, timeout, keyserver

Here is what I'm getting:

```
marco@marco-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-
keyservers.net --recv-key 421C365BD9FF1F717815A3895523BAEEB01FA116
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --
homedir /tmp/tmp.CPcLK5j7k0 --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --
keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg -
keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-key 
421C365BD9FF1F717815A3895523BAEEB01FA116
gpg: requesting key B01FA116 from hkp server ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net
gpg: keyserver timed out
gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error
```

And here's what I have tried:

```
-forcing through :80 port in case firewall was blocking the default one.
     >>> did not work

-iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -d 0/0 -s 0/0 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -d 0/0 -s 0/0 --dport 11371 -j ACCEPT
     >>> did not work

- sudo ufw disable (disable firewall)
     >>> did not work
```

The only thing that I can think of at this point is something I read on another post where someone suggested accessing the server manually and copying the key contents into a textfile and adding it authenticate in on my system. But I do not know how to access the server directly.

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

This [apt-get stuck at 0 [Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com]](https://askubuntu.com/a/575130/650485) solved my problem. All I had to do was make sure uncomment a line in `/etc/gai.conf` and that fixed it.