# Can't connect to ubuntu archive when using apt-get update

Tags: 16.04, apt, upgrade, updates

I am trying to `apt-get update` but it gets stuck on

`0% [Connecting to ph.archive.ubuntu.com (202.90.159.172)]`

and after a couple of minutes it gives me the following:

```
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]     
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Err:3 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
  Could not connect to ph.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:d18:0:23::172). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:d18:0:23::172 80]
Err:4 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
  Unable to connect to ph.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:d18:0:23::172 80]
Err:5 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
  Unable to connect to ph.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:d18:0:23::172 80]
Fetched 102 kB in 2min 0s (846 B/s)                      
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Could not connect to ph.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:d18:0:23::172). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:d18:0:23::172 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease  Unable to connect to ph.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:d18:0:23::172 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/InRelease  Unable to connect to ph.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 2001:d18:0:23::172 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have tried disabling IPV6 connection as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/574569/apt-get-stuck-at-0-connecting-to-us-archive-ubuntu-com) but it doesn't seem to fix the problem. What should I do? I'm an Ubuntu newb and using 16.04.

Comment: Same problem with `in.archive.ubuntu.com` or even `archive.ubuntu.com`. But surprisingly internet browser is working, `ping` and `host -v ` resolution is working as well.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that something is wrong with your mirrors.

If you run `nslookup ph.archive.ubuntu.com` you get the IP of server which is: `202.90.159.172`, but if you try to `ping` it: `ping ph.archive.ubuntu.com` you're not going to get any response.

Also if you have look at [Ubuntu mirrors list](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors), you can see that this mirror does not exist there, I guess it's down for a while.

Change your mirrors, then update your sources.

A fast workaround is to use sed to change `ph` with `us` mirrors:

```
sudo sed -i s/ph.archive/us.archive/  /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this in a Dockerfile and get `'/bin/sh -c sudo sed -i s/us.archive/nz.archive/  /etc/apt/sources.list' returned a non-zero code: 127`