# When I am doing sudo apt-get update I got stuck at this :

Tags: 16.04, updates

0% [Connecting to in.archive.ubuntu.com (2001:67c:1560:8001::14)] [Connecting to security.ubuntu.com (2001:67c:1360:8001::17)]

Comment: You may try [disabling ipv6](https://askubuntu.com/a/484487/260379).

Comment: Do you use any VPN. if so, disable VPN and try again, if still not working try disable ipv6.

Answer (score 1):

You receive this error because APT is trying to use IPv6. Quick fix it's to set APT only for IPv4, run the following command to create a configuration file for APT.

**`sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99force-ipv4`**

Copy and paste the following line into the file.

**`Acquire::ForceIPv4 "true";`**

Save and close the file. From now on, APT will use IPv4 only.

Comment: In which extension do i have to save this file?

Comment: just copy paste /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99force-ipv4

Comment: also if not working my answer take a look here:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/574569/apt-get-stuck-at-0-connecting-to-us-archive-ubuntu-com?noredirect=1&lq=1