# sudo apt-get is stuck at 0%

Tags: 14.04, apache2, php

I am using an apache2 server(Ubuntu). I am trying to install the package called `php7.0-sybase`. But downloading it is stuck in 0%

> 0% [Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.26)]

I tried pinging `us.archive.ubuntu.com` and `91.189.91.26` and that's fine.

I also tried `sudo apt-get update` which is also stuck at 0%

I have installed packages in this server before but never had this problem until today. Pls help!

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: I tried that too.. But it doesn't work! and also - that link has an ipv6 ubuntu ip and i have an ipv4 ip (91.189.91.26)

Comment: Ah, I see. Maybe also not the exactly same problem, but you could try looking at https://askubuntu.com/q/156650/367990 or https://askubuntu.com/q/498462/367990 as well...

Answer (score 1):

You can also try `apt-mirror` method. For example a line in your /etc/apt/sources.list could be:

`deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt zesty main restricted`