# Ubuntu 18.04.2: Conventional install of pip does not work

Tags: apt, 18.04, python, pip

i'm trying to install pip with `sudo apt install python-pip`, and its like the repository is dead because I got this message during the "installation" : `Réception de:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 gcc-7 amd64 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04 [7 455 kB]`
I have already run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` but without success.

Here is my sources.list file:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Can you please [edit] your question and put the whole error message into it. Thank you.

Comment: Could you post the full output you see when trying to install pip please, the above doesn't appear to be an error just the standard apt progress output.

Comment: That is the problem, only this message: Réception de:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 gcc-7 amd64 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04 [7 455 kB] appears when I start the installation, and it is re-displayed indefinitly

Comment: Does the progress bar say where it's up to?? To be honest the above is not an error so it's going to be difficult to work out where/what the problem might be without more info. From the above what it looks/sounds like to me is that you have a very slow internet connection and it's taking a long time to download the package. Does the problem happen with apt-upgrade or any other packages??

Comment: I've had a quick search for generic issues with apt freezing and there's a few suggestions here https://askubuntu.com/questions/498462/apt-get-stuck-at-0-working