# How do I remount a filesystem read/write?

Tags: mount

My cat walked over my keyboard and pressed "magical" SysRq u, doing an Emergency Remount R/O.  **How do I reverse this?**

On [How do I remount a filesystem as read/write?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175739/how-do-i-remount-a-filesystem-as-read-write/175742), SirCharlo claims

> The correct syntax is:
>
> ```
> sudo mount -o remount,rw /partition/identifier /mount/point
> ```

but that just yields another error,

```
mount: you must specify the filesystem type
```

and if I supply it, e.g.,

```
$ sudo mount -t ext4 -o remount,rw /dev/sda7 /
```

I'm back at the error message the OP reported,

```
mount: / not mounted or bad option
```

That diagnostic begs the question, which?  Not mounted, or bad option?  The exit status is 32, and `man mount` provides this key:

```
  mount has the following return codes (the bits can be ORed):
  0      success
  1      incorrect invocation or permissions
  2      system error (out of memory, cannot fork, no more loop devices)
  4      internal mount bug
  8      user interrupt
  16     problems writing or locking /etc/mtab
  32     mount failure
  64     some mount succeeded
```

OK, looks like a mount failure. ;-)
What can I do about it?

BTW, in response to Alkthree's question "How do I remount", SirCharlo also suggest *not* a remount but umount followed by mount.  Why?

Comment: I deleted my answer; on a second thought, that's probably just not reversible. What if a process tries to remount the system read/write after you remounted everything with an emergency remount? I think that's just actively inhibited to forbid any process to go against the emergency remount. Nevertheless +1 for the good question, and I'll research this a bit and post again if I find something since this intrigued me.

Comment: Bummer.  Thanks kos.  Meanwhile, the failing system call is `mount("/dev/sda7", "/", 0x1fa8590, MS_MGC_VAL|MS_REMOUNT, "errors=remount-ro") = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)` as reported by strace.

Comment: Try to execute `sudo mount -o remount,rw /`.

Comment: @Hi-Angel : that's exactly what kos suggested (and what I had tried before asking), and what yields `mount: / not mounted or bad option` because the system call `mount(...)` fails -- see above.

Comment: @Quigi the command I asked is with removed partition identifier — just for the safe case: you know, like, perhaps could be that "remount" option doesn't expect both partition and the path, or something alike… I just know that this command works for sure. But if that still won't work, it would be great if you would post output of `mount`, without options.

Comment: @Hi-Angel: Yes, kos and I did exactly that, with removed partition identifier.  When I (as root) run `mount -o remount,rw /`, that program (`/bin/mount`) figures out the partition identifier by itself, and attempts the system call `mount("/dev/sda7", "/", 0x19f6590, MS_MGC_VAL|MS_REMOUNT, "errors=remount-ro")`, which returns `-1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)`, and then it prints `mount: / not mounted or bad option`.

Comment: mount without options produces this output that's too long by 900 or so characters, and ends with this crucial note about its staleness:  `mount: warning: /etc/mtab is not writable (e.g. read-only filesystem).
       It's possible that information reported by mount(8) is not
       up to date. For actual information about system mount points
       check the /proc/mounts file.`

Comment: The first (stale!) row reports a partition mounted on "/", namely `/dev/sda7 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro,commit=0)`.  In contrast, the up-to-date /proc/mounts has **two**, `rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0` and
`/dev/disk/by-uuid/3a1bce3b-90fa-423f-9bee-69874fd7a9c1 / ext4 ro,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered 0 0`

Comment: Okay, I don't know what to do, but a couple of thoughts of what I'd do here: try to look at the `/var/log/syslog` and `dmesg` for anything file system related, especially for the moment when the filesystem was remounted, and anything related to `/dev/sda7`. Run `tail -f /var/log/syslog`, and try to run the `mount -o remount,rw /` again, also try to press again the *Alt+SysRq+u* — and see if there would be any prints.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33346/discussion-between-quigi-and-hi-angel).

Comment: I asked about fixing, and that may be impossible.  But it may be preventable.  My /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq contains 176.  According to https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysrq.txt, that bitmask allows 3 functions:           16 =  0x10 - enable sync command;
         32 =  0x20 - enable remount read-only;
        128 =  0x80 - allow reboot/poweroff.  To disable remount read-only, I can change it to 0x10 | 0x80:  
`echo 144 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq`