# changing ownership of Read-only file system - i cant move, delete , rename any file

Tags: filesystem

I have a problem with my Ubuntu 17 machine, I can't rename or delete any file on my hard drive, I get this error:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A Read-Only Filesystem generally occurs when something goes wrong and the system decides it's safest to go read-only.

The solution is to remount the system as read-write.

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /partition/identifier /mount/point
```

You can find the mount point with this command:

```
mount -v | grep "^/" | awk '{print "\nPartition identifier: " $1  "\n Mountpoint: "  $3}'
```

You might need to unmount if already mounted.

Source: [How do I remount a filesystem as read/write?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175739/how-do-i-remount-a-filesystem-as-read-write)