# Creating directory on cifs mount returns error, but directory is indeed created

Tags: mount, samba, cifs, mkdir

I have mounted an external disk connected to an ASUS router, which implements a Samba server. Everything works just fine except one annoying thing: creating a directory with mkdir returns an error message, even though the directory is indeed created.

The relevant line in `/etc/fstab` looks like this:

`//192.168.1.1/data /media/external/data cifs username=data,password=data,vers=2.0,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0`

When mounting the disk, everything is ok. (The directory `stackoverflow` is located on the external disk.)

```
daniel@nuc:/media/external$ ll
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 5 root     root     4096 mar 23 21:05 ./
drwxr-xr-x 4 root     root     4096 mar 10 15:25 ../
drwxr-xr-x 2 daniel   daniel   4096 mar 24 10:50 data/
daniel@nuc:/media/external$ sudo mount -a
daniel@nuc:/media/external$ cd data
daniel@nuc:/media/external/data$ ll
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 daniel daniel    0 mar 24 10:54 ./
drwxr-xr-x 5 root   root   4096 mar 23 21:05 ../
drwxr-xr-x 2 daniel daniel    0 mar 14 23:07 stackoverflow/
daniel@nuc:/media/external/data$
```

When creating the directory `test`, an error message is shown.

```
daniel@nuc:/media/external/data$ mkdir test
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘test’: Not a directory
```

However, the directory is created!

```
daniel@nuc:/media/external/data$ ll
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 daniel daniel    0 mar 24 11:01 ./
drwxr-xr-x 5 root   root   4096 mar 23 21:05 ../
drwxr-xr-x 2 daniel daniel    0 mar 14 23:07 stackoverflow/
drwxr-xr-x 2 daniel daniel    0 mar 24 11:01 test/
```

When removing the directory and recreating it with the `-p` flag, the error message does not show up.

```
daniel@nuc:/media/external/data$ rmdir test
daniel@nuc:/media/external/data$ ll
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 daniel daniel    0 mar 24 11:01 ./
drwxr-xr-x 5 root   root   4096 mar 23 21:05 ../
drwxr-xr-x 2 daniel daniel    0 mar 14 23:07 stackoverflow/
daniel@nuc:/media/external/data$ mkdir -p test
daniel@nuc:/media/external/data$ ll
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 daniel daniel    0 mar 24 11:01 ./
drwxr-xr-x 5 root   root   4096 mar 23 21:05 ../
drwxr-xr-x 2 daniel daniel    0 mar 14 23:07 stackoverflow/
drwxr-xr-x 2 daniel daniel    0 mar 24 11:01 test/
daniel@nuc:/media/external/data$
```

This makes me wonder if the problem is that mkdir does not "see" the mounted directory for some reason and spits out an error message just as if you would try to created a sub-directory within an non-existing directory.

But why is this? What can I do to fix it?

(I will add that when mounting with `vers=1.0`, the mkdir error does not show. However, `file_mode` and `dir_mode` then appear to be ignored, and I need them to be set to `0700` in another application.)

Update: When the disk is connected to the USB port of the computer and ntfs mounted everything works nicely.

Update: Output from `strace mkdir test`

```
execve("/bin/mkdir", ["mkdir", "test"], 0x7ffdb3669768 /* 67 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x561761838000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=158495, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 158495, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f782b715000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\20b\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=154832, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f782b713000
mmap(NULL, 2259152, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f782b2ed000
mprotect(0x7f782b312000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f782b511000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x24000) = 0x7f782b511000
mmap(0x7f782b513000, 6352, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f782b513000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\260\34\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2030544, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4131552, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f782aefc000
mprotect(0x7f782b0e3000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f782b2e3000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1e7000) = 0x7f782b2e3000
mmap(0x7f782b2e9000, 15072, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f782b2e9000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0 \25\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=464824, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2560264, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f782ac8a000
mprotect(0x7f782acfa000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f782aefa000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x70000) = 0x7f782aefa000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P\16\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=14560, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2109712, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f782aa86000
mprotect(0x7f782aa89000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f782ac88000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7f782ac88000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0000b\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=144976, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2221184, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f782a867000
mprotect(0x7f782a881000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f782aa80000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x19000) = 0x7f782aa80000
mmap(0x7f782aa82000, 13440, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f782aa82000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f782b711000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f782b712040) = 0
mprotect(0x7f782b2e3000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f782aa80000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f782ac88000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f782aefa000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f782b511000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x56175ffd9000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f782b73c000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f782b715000, 158495)          = 0
set_tid_address(0x7f782b712310)         = 7736
set_robust_list(0x7f782b712320, 24)     = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {sa_handler=0x7f782a86ccb0, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x7f782a879890}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {sa_handler=0x7f782a86cd50, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0x7f782a879890}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_STACK, NULL, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
statfs("/sys/fs/selinux", 0x7fff4f557960) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
statfs("/selinux", 0x7fff4f557960)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
brk(NULL)                               = 0x561761838000
brk(0x561761859000)                     = 0x561761859000
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/filesystems", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
read(3, "nodev\tsysfs\nnodev\trootfs\nnodev\tr"..., 1024) = 420
read(3, "", 1024)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/selinux/config", F_OK)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=11861168, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 11861168, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f7829d17000
close(3)                                = 0
mkdir("test", 0777)                     = -1 ENOTDIR (Not a directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2995, ...}) = 0
read(3, "# Locale name alias data base.\n#"..., 4096) = 2995
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en/LC_MESSAGES/coreutils.mo", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=578, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 578, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f782b73b000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/charset.alias", O_RDONLY|O_NOFOLLOW) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "mkdir: ", 7mkdir: )                  = 7
write(2, "cannot create directory \342\200\230test\342"..., 34cannot create directory ‘test’) = 34
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, ": Not a directory", 17: Not a directory)       = 17
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
close(1)                                = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

Update on request, the `smb.conf` file from the ASUS router (somewhat tidied, relevant parts kept):

```
[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
netbios name = RT-AC68U-AC48
server string = RT-AC68U-AC48
unix charset = UTF8
display charset = UTF8
load printers = no
printing = bsd
printcap name = /dev/null
log file = /var/log.samba
log level = 0
max log size = 5
security = USER
guest ok = no
map to guest = Bad User
encrypt passwords = yes
pam password change = no
null passwords = yes
force directory mode = 0777
force create mode = 0777
max connections = 5
socket options = IPTOS_LOWDELAY TCP_NODELAY SO_KEEPALIVE
obey pam restrictions = no
disable spoolss = yes
host msdfs = no
strict allocate = no
wide links = no
bind interfaces only = yes
interfaces = lo br0 192.168.1.1/255.255.255.0 
use sendfile = yes
map archive = no
map hidden = no
map read only = no
map system = no
store dos attributes = yes
dos filemode = yes
oplocks = yes
level2 oplocks = yes
kernel oplocks = no
enable core files = no
deadtime = 30
load printers = no
printable = no
max protocol = SMB2
min protocol = SMB2
smb encrypt = disabled
min receivefile size = 16384
passdb backend = smbpasswd
smb passwd file = /etc/samba/smbpasswd
[data]
comment = Seagate_3TB's data in Seagate Backup+ Desk
path = /tmp/mnt/Seagate_3TB/data
dos filetimes = yes
fake directory create times = yes
valid users = data, backup
invalid users = backup
read list = data
write list = data
```

Creating the directory when ssh'd onto the router works as expected (perhaps not very surprising):

```
daniel@RT-AC68U-AC48:/tmp/mnt/Seagate_3TB/data# ll
drwxrwxrwx    1 daniel root             0 Mar 15 00:07 stackoverflow/
daniel@RT-AC68U-AC48:/tmp/mnt/Seagate_3TB/data# mkdir test
daniel@RT-AC68U-AC48:/tmp/mnt/Seagate_3TB/data# ll
drwxrwxrwx    1 daniel root             0 Mar 15 00:07 stackoverflow/
drwxrwxrwx    1 daniel root             0 Apr  3 21:46 test/
```

Comment: If you're running Ubuntu, this is perfectly on topic here. There's no reason to migrate. If you would rather have it on [linux.se], you can always just delete it and repost it there. I'm happy to migrate if you insist, but since it's on topic here, I don't really see any reason to.

Comment: The `-p` flag suppresses warnings, so I'd say it's normal that you don't see anything.  Can you show us the output of `rmdir test; strace mkdir test`?

Comment: @terdon No reason to migrate, I agree! I updated the post with the output of `strace mkdir test`.

Comment: @DanielR Could you provide your smb.conf and user that is executing samba on sharing side. Also mount command that is used to mount device on asus router.

Comment: This has to do with the permissions and access credentials to the samba resource.
Check that the configuration of the Samba Server is correct when defining the resource.

Try mounting it manually. Then enter it into the fstab.

Comment: @PasiSuominen I dug out the smb.conf file (see updated post), but didn't yet do the other stuff you recommended. I'm not very confident in playing around on the router, but fwiw it is running Asuswrt-merlin. I'm not sure what to make of it all, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: @CarlosDagorret, pinging you as well. See the updated post with the smb.conf file.`/etc/fstab` was empty on the router by the way.

Comment: @DanielR when you type mount, you can see all mounts. Is there reason than your disk should be in NTFS format? Could be easier to use ext2 or similar with unix permissions.

Comment: @PasiSuominen Result from mount: `/dev/sda on /tmp/mnt/Seagate_3TB type tntfs (rw,nodev,relatime,uid=0,gid=0,umask=00,allow_utime=0022,nls=utf8,min_prealloc_size=64k,max_prealloc_size=128M,readahead=1M,user_xattr,case_sensitive,nocache,fail_safe,hidden=show,dotfile=show,protected_system=show,errors=continue,mft_zone_multiplier=1)` I could try to format the disk in another format (or try another one...).

Comment: Okay, I think this have something to do with ntfs acl:s, or another strange combination with ntfs - kernel communication. Try to change disk partition to eg. ext2 or something similar and see if the problem still persist.

Comment: @PasiSuominen I think you got it! I created an ext3 partition on the disk and and after connecting it to the router and cifs mounting it on my computer, the `mkdir` error was no more. If you want to write up an answer, I’d be happy to upvote and accept it.

Comment: I don't have real answer, that was just a lucky quess based on ntfs mount and cifs interoperation. If someone know the exact bug where the timing on system calls go wrong, that would be the answer we are looking to. Happy you get your share to work without errors.

Comment: It seems to be the same error related to ASUS routers with Merlin firmware as described here: https://www.snbforums.com/threads/samba-shared-drive-folder-errors.54457/ A solution is claimed to be here (have not tested by myself; I am having the same issue):
https://www.snbforums.com/threads/error-0x8007010b-on-rt-ax88u.54205/#post-456168

Answer (score -1):

This could be a dying hard-drive/SSD that `mkdir` is failing to write to.

Since this is an external drive. Does it have a read-write lock on?

It could be mounted as read-only instead of read+write.

Use: `sudo mount -o remount,rw /partition/identifier /mount/point` to re-mount as read+write. Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/175742/886917.

Comment: I will try what you suggest as soon as I can, but I just wanted to clarify that the folder is indeed created and I have no trouble using for example `rsync` to copy massive amounts of data to the disk.

Comment: FYI, your suggestion didn't work. Thanks for trying to help, appreciated!