# Can't create file: Read-only file system

Tags: command-line, permissions, read-only, adb

I was trying to recover files from android phone using adb shell and test disk. But I am getting a read only filesystem error, even though the permissions to write is granted to the user.

```
adb devices
```

list the device attached.
After I ran the following commands

```
adb shell
```

Inside the shell I did the following

```
user:/ $ su
user:/ # adb shell "stty raw; cat </dev/block/mmcblk0p56" > data.img
sh: can't create data.img: Read-only file system
```

How to solve this?

**Update**

Trying the proposed solutions:

```
 $ sudo adb shell "stty raw; cat /dev/block/mmcblk0p56" > /home/user/android-backup/data.img
stty: tcgetattr standard input: Not a typewriter
cat: /dev/block/mmcblk0p56: Permission denied
```

Mounting code:

```
$ sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/block/mmcblk0p56 /tmp
mount: /tmp: mount point not mounted or bad option.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to remount the file system with read and write permissions ([source](https://askubuntu.com/a/175742/566421)):

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /partition/identifier /mount/point
```

Or in your case you just can tray to redirect the output to a file located in a directory where you must be able to write:

```
adb shell "stty raw; cat </dev/block/mmcblk0p56" > /tmp/data.img
```

Comment: I would add 'writing to / is always a bad idea (not related if possible or not)'. But your suggestion to use /tmp covers the solution already.

Comment: Hi, @LupusE, why it is a bad idea?

Comment: There is something called FSH (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) to define what data should be stored in which directory. ... It is very important if you've got different partitions for different purposes. For example: Avoid to put /var/log on a flash storage. Much read/write will kill it ... It is the same if you store everything on C: in windows. Maybe good for the moment, but don't show anyone.

Comment: @pa4080 Is /partition/identifier in this case /dev/block/mmcblk0p56? Also, what should be the mount point?

Comment: @supremum, yes I think it should be `/dev/block/mmcblk0p56`, but can't be sure. You can list the attached drives/devices by the command `sudo lsblk`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to copy the block device to an image file on your local computer? If so, try:

```
adb shell su -c '"stty raw; cat < /dev/block/mmcblk0p56"' > data.img
```