# Drive Partition is Read-Only in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, permissions, read-only

I have a physical drive with several partitions. There is an Ubuntu/Windows dual-boot on this drive.

```
sudo lsblk
sdb      8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   100M  0 part /media/System_Reserved
├─sdb2   8:18   0 199.9G  0 part /media/user/9486423786421A5E
├─sdb3   8:19   0   100G  0 part /
├─sdb4   8:20   0     1K  0 part 
└─sdb5   8:21   0 631.5G  0 part /media/user/Playground
```

Also,

```
user@user-desktop:~$ sudo df -HT
/dev/sdb5      fuseblk   679G  512G  167G  76% /media/user/Playground
```

Lastly,

```
user@user-desktop:~$ sudo fdisk -l
    Device     Boot     Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
    /dev/sdb1  *         2048     206847     204800   100M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
    /dev/sdb2          206848  419430399  419223552 199.9G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
    /dev/sdb3       419430400  629145599  209715200   100G 83 Linux
    /dev/sdb4       629145600 1953521663 1324376064 631.5G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
    /dev/sdb5       629147648 1953521663 1324374016 631.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

I can create and erase files on `/dev/sdb2`, but not on `/dev/sdb5`, although these appear to be mounted similarly. I have tried some mount and unmount suggestions outlined [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175739/how-do-i-remount-a-filesystem-as-read-write), but they didn't seem to help.

How can I make this partition writeable from Ubuntu?

**Edit:**

Another bit of information is presented when I inspect the mounts

```
sudo mount -l
    /dev/sdb5 on /media/user/Playground type fuseblk (rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096) [Playground]
    /dev/sdb2 on /media/user/9486423786421A5E type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096,user)
```

Comment: Could you add the output of `ls -l /media/user` and `id`?

Comment: Is fast startup enabled in Windows? If so, that is known to cause problems with writing to NTFS partitions from Linux. Try disabling it (by running `powercfg /h off` in an administrator command prompt) and see if that makes any difference